# How to bind the Observable<any> single class object in HTML

Tags: angular, timer, binding, observable

I am using Angular4. I have a Windows Timer subscribed observable in my typescript file.

```
    this.dynamicTime = new Observable<string>((observer: Subscriber<string>) => {
        setInterval(() => observer.next(this.computeTime()), 1000);
    });
```

In my HTML side, I am using it like this.

```
<h1>
<div>{{ dynamicTime | async }}</div>
```

This works great.

But if I change the type of the variable "dynamicTime" from `Observable<string>` to `Observable<SomeClass>` class object. Then It's not working. The funny thing is the windows timer itself fails. The control will not hit the timer function "computeTime()".

This is how the change looks.

```
    this.dynamicTime = new Observable<SomeClass>((observer: Subscriber<SomeClass>) => {
        setInterval(() => observer.next(this.computeTime()), 1000);
    });
```

On the HTML side,

```
   <h1>
<div>{{ dynamicTime.someProperty | async }}</div>
```

Looks like the HTML side is not recognizing the "someProperty". The "someProperty" is declared as public in the class "SomeClass".

Not sure what I am missing here. Please advise.

Thanks
Adam

Comment: How does your `computeTime` function look like?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`dynamicTime`  is an `Observable`. It hasn't property with name `someProperty`.

In order to get property you should first unwrap observable by using async pipe. AsyncPipe subscribes to observable and returns `SomeClass` instance which has `someProperty` property.

I would do it like

```
{{ (dynamicTime | async)?.someProperty }}
```

**[Plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/NETLHk1xyCfBeIB1S3kC?p=preview)**

Note i also use here safe navigation operator `?.` to be able to prevent error when object is not resolved

Comment: I applied this fix and it works perfectly. Thank you. But is there a difference between "dynamicTime.someProperty | async" and "dynamicTime | async)?.someProperty" ?